# Multiple order by on the same table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have 3 simple selects:

```
select * from `table` order by `id` desc limit 10

select * from `table` order by `date` desc limit 10

select * from `table` order by `name` desc limit 10
```

Is it possible to combine those three in one query?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want three result sets? Or one?

Comment: I'd like three result sets. Ultimately, I need 3 lists each limited to 10 items.

Comment: @Bastien . . . Then why do you want one query?

Comment: I agree with Gordon, if you want three results sets then three queries makes sense.

Comment: Alright. I was wondering what was more efficient. 3 different selects vs merging them in 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
(select * from `table` order by `id` desc limit 10)
union all
(select * from `table` order by `date` desc limit 10)
union all
(select * from `table` order by `name` desc limit 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`:

```
(select * from `table` order by `id` desc limit 10) T1
UNION
(select * from `table` order by `date` desc limit 10) T2
UNION
(select * from `table` order by `name` desc limit 10) T3
```

If you need duplicates as well, replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one result set just use a comma separated list of column identifiers to [order by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html):

```
select * from `table` order by `id` desc, `date` desc, `name` desc limit 10
```

This will order by `id`, then if IDs are the same, order by `date`, and if date is the same, order by `name`.

If you want three results sets, use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
(select * from `table` order by `id` desc limit 10)
union all
(select * from `table` order by `date` desc limit 10)
union all
(select * from `table` order by `name` desc limit 10)
```